# fixing one div to second div top right corner with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following divs

```
<div id="outer"><img src="myimgpath"><div id="name">Username</div></div>
```

How do I fix the inner div to the outer div's top right corner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

#name {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems not to work at all.  In Firefox, the "Username" isn't visible.  In Chrome, the "Username" appears when it first renders, not anchored to the top-right of the image, and disappears as soon as you resize the page. [(Here's a Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/FourOhs/ynj5n2ys/)  Absolute positioning is absolute, not relative to its container.

Comment: @JMD The div the image is contained in is a block level element. The image itself has a fixed width. Absolute positioning is relative to its nearest "relative" container. [Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0ykbzb7/)

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="outer" style="position:relative">
  <img src="myimgpath">
  <div id="name" style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;">Username</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is absolute.  The OP wants it relative to the #outer div.

Answer (score 3):

add `float:right;` to the inner div